# Is a wave packet a superposition of standing waves? How is the wave packet in 3D (real world)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, hilbert-space, wavefunction, superposition

The wave function that is non zero in a finite space, that represents the free particle - is it formed by the interaction of standing waves or traveling waves? And a second question: everybody describes a free particle by a wave function always moving in one dimension, how would be in our real world with 3 dimensions? Would the waves packets in a 3D world be like a sphere or cylinder occupying a volume?

Comment: It depends on the boundary conditions. If you take the finite space to have zero possibility to have an amplitude on the boundaries, you will get a standing wave in the end (even if it travels in the beginning). However if you take your space to be periodic (like a circle, sphere, etc) then the packet wave could be a superposition of all the possible waves, standing or traveling, that can occur in that finite and periodic space. Of course the wave lengths would be quantized (discrete).

Comment: Wave functions are not real, they are only used for calculating. So neither question can be answered physically.

Answer (score 1):

> The wave function who is non zero in a finite space, who represent the free particle, is it formed by the interaction of standing waves or travelling waves?

It could be either. The main difference between wave functions formed from travelling and standing waves is whether it carries a flux (=probability current.) Term *wave-packet* is usually applied to a superposition of waves with a rather narrow spectrum around the central frequency/eigenvalue.

> And a second question: everybody describes a free particle by a wave function always moving in one dimension, how would be in our real
> world with 3 dimensions?

One-dimensional description is used in introductory quantum mechanics textbooks, mainly for pedagogical purposes. Yet, even those textbooks contain many three-dimensional problems - just look up the chapters on the hydrogen atom or the general scattering theory.

> Would the waves packets in a 3D world be like a sphere or cylinder occupying a volume?

If particles are bound (inside a sphere or cylinder), they obviously occupy a volume, although the probability density does not have to be uniform in this volume.